# Scrape domain with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape domain list from sameip.org with BeautifulSoup, My code as follows :

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, re, io, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

resp = opener.open('http://sameip.org/ip/141.101.125.122').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp)
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    for x in tds:
        print x
```

working bat scrape more data, I need scrape only domain name, example :

```
tcjayfund.org
fjminc.com
amandabillyrock.com
fjmclinics.com
```

How can I make this ?

Comment: As a side note, why are you using a `CookieJar` here? I can't understand what you expect a default-constructed cookie jar to help when you're just doing a single request. And from a quick test, I get the exact same page back with or without it.

Comment: because im use script copy and paste from anather script .. is not need .. i remove .. for new i need scrape the url !

Comment: Don't just copy and paste random code without trying to understand what it does. Read the `urllib2` docs and see what it does. `urllib2.urlopen('http://sameip.org/ip/141.101.125.122').read()` is all you need here. (And you don't need to import a half-dozen modules you never use, either.)

Comment: ok, now is more cleen, bat how can print only domain name list ?

Comment: Please see my answer. On this site, people put side comments in comments, and answers to the actual problem in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at what your code prints out, clearly the first row is a header row, and in every subsequent row, the second column is the domain. So:

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print tds[1].text.strip()
```

Or, if you want to grab them all into a list instead of printing them:

```
domains = [tr.find_all('td')[1].text.strip() for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]]
```

In a better-designed site, you'd want to use IDs and structural relationships rather than fixed indices like this, but when they've just got bare, dumb tables like this, there's really no way around it.